# Operation with view column in mysql

Tags: mysql, view

I recently started working with view and this question arose - is it possible to perform any operations on the calculated columns in the view? For example, there is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.table(
row_id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
val1 DOUBLE,
val2 DOUBLE);
```

In val1 and val2 are entered arbitrary data:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO schema.table (va1, val2) VALUES (5, 6);
```

I try to create a view based on the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
VIEW schema.table_VIEW
AS select
t1.row_id as row_id, 
LAG (val3,1,0) OVER() + t1.val1 - t1.val2 as val3,
from 
schema.table t1
```

and I get the error that val3 does not exist in the table, which in general is logical. Tell me, can this somehow be implemented? The goal of the view is to get a column val3, in which the value from this column in the last row will look and val1 will be added and val2 will be subtracted from the current one.

And question number 2 - if you create a column val4 in the table, will it be possible to update it dynamically with values from val3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically a Rolling Sum problem, where previous row's **Sum** is added to the current row's calculations, to calculate the current row's **Sum**. You can rather use [Frames](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) here. `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` with `SUM()` function can be used to consider the Sum of `val1 - val2` values from the first row upto the current row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
VIEW schema.table_VIEW
AS select
     t1.row_id as row_id, 
     SUM(t1.val1 - t1.val2) OVER(ORDER BY t1.row_id
                                 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS val3
   from 
     schema.table t1
```

---

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(
row_id INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
val1 DOUBLE,
val2 DOUBLE);

INSERT INTO test (val1, val2) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO test (val1, val2) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO test (val1, val2) VALUES (5, 6);

CREATE OR REPLACE
VIEW test_VIEW
AS select
     t1.row_id as row_id, 
     SUM(t1.val1 - t1.val2) OVER(ORDER BY t1.row_id
                                 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS val3
   from 
     test t1
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from test_VIEW;

| row_id | val3 |
| ------ | ---- |
| 1      | -1   |
| 2      | -2   |
| 3      | -3   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t37LEksC1Y1RJLcGxfLWBG/1)

Comment: thanks for the answer!
could you tell me how to write dynamically the result of such calculations from view to a table?

Comment: @mysqllearn does this answer solve the first part of your problem ?

Comment: not really, but I did not know about such a function of access to data from other lines, thanks
I need to perform an operation with the already calculated value from the last line, and not to do the calculation twice, this will affect the performance

Comment: @mysqllearn I don't think that it will be having performance issues; as MySQL optimizer should be taking note of already calculated values. Nevertheless, can you confirm that query is getting expected results or not ? If yes, I can work out another approach using user defined variables, which will not be "doing calculations twice"

Comment: I have carefully studied the functionality _ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING_ and I can say that yes, that query is getting expected results and solves my problem.